# Grub rescue screen appears on installation

Tags: linux, boot, grub

So, I have download the Garuda mate Desktop Environment and make a bootable flashdrive using rufus in GPT (UEFI) mode but when I boot the pendrive show like this

```
error : unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >
```

before it I had installed another linux and it was successfully installed and after some days I remove it from my PC
How do I fix it?

Comment: And your question is...? Do you have (or should have) any **working** OS in that computer?

Comment: Yes it is Windows10

Comment: So, next time (or even *this* time by [edit]ing the question) make sure to post all the relevant details. If your unstated problem is Windows not booting then probably you need to learn about UEFI mode and its boot process and go to UEFI settings > Boot menu and change the boot order back to Windows bootloader manager as that will make you Windows to boot directly. Later you can clean up the remaining Grub installation in the ESP. If you don't know this details you should learn about it *before* installation another OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  My windows is working perfectly fine I dual booted it, my problem is I am not able to install Garuda linux, when ever I choose the bootable pendrive from boot menu it shows the grub rescue screen not the installation screen

Comment: Too much possibilities: (1) Corrupt ISO (2) improper burning to USB, improper tool used, etc. (3) rare but also possible, UEFI needs some settings changed in order to boot from external media.

Answer (score 0):

> using rufus in GPT (UEFI) mode

Then there's something puzzling about your setup, because if you use the latest version of Rufus along with the latest version of Garuda mate (`garuda-mate-linux-zen-220131.iso`), the first thing you will see in Rufus is a prompt telling you that the image selected is incompatible with *ISO mode* and therefore that *DD mode* will be enforced.

This means that, if using the latest version of Rufus, you will **NOT** be able to change the partition scheme to GPT.

So it looks like you are using an old release of Rufus for some reason, and end up in a situation that newer releases of Rufus are precisely designed to avoid.

Please retry with Rufus 3.17 (latest version at the time of this post) and `garuda-mate-linux-zen-220131.iso` and, if you are doing it intentionally, please do not attempt to circumvent application features that are designed to avoid precisely the kind of issues you will run into if you try to force your way around specific restrictions.

For the record, it really doesn't matter one bit if the partition scheme of your USB drive is GPT or MBR when booting in UEFI mode, as this will have no incidence whatsoever on the partition scheme of the Linux system you are going to install.

Comment: yeah thanks, but there is another error occurred " ERROR :'/dev/disk/by-label/Garuda' device did not show up after 30seconds..."

Comment: Again, the error you report will not happen if you write the ISO in DD mode, as Rufus 3.17 will do. Have you actually tried recreating the bootable drive with Rufus 3.17?

Comment: this time I used Rufus 3.17 with MBR, and a popup appears "DD image will be enforced". When i booted it, the Garuda installation windows open when I clicked the installation option then the error appears that I have mentioned in the previous comment. Perhaps Thanks you so much for your effort.

Comment: Then you may want to report it to the Garuda team, because when written in DD mode (which is what Rufus did) everything is created as the distro maintainers set it up, so, if it doesn't work, the issue lies with how the distro maintainers created the image. Oh, and in case they attempt to deflect the issue by saying that Rufus might be the issue, please try with balena Etcher or even the `dd` command in Linux if you can, as you should get the same results and be able to prove to them that the issue *is* with how they created the ISO and not the application that wrote it.